# AngularJS - Modular Search Page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-directive

So I have been plowing the internet to understand or see and example of what I want to do.

It shouldn't be difficult, but something is just missing to me.

## The Scenario

I have a search page, built from 2 directives/ ui-views like this:
[image]

## What I want to achieve

When I press `Search`, I want to trigger the `Search Results` directive/ view to fetch the corresponding results based on the search form parameter.

## Where I am stuck

Because I have 2 separate directives, I can make them share information using the parent controller, OR the search service I have (to communicate with the backend).
However, The `search` directive can write information to either one, BUT the results are still not triggered. Unless I actively check for changes every once in a while for changes, I won't get the *cling* saying I have been triggered.

That is definitely not the the AngularJS way, and I just don't seem to have enough experience to think of something else.

## What I am asking you

How would you approach this situation, what will you use to make this page as clean as you can, and modular (of course).
I've had ideas that at the worst case scenario, I will omit the `modular` approach, and just do it dirty, but working.
Still, this annoys me because as far as I know, this is one of the STRONGEST features of Angular.

#### I'd appreciate if you could attach some code for all to see and learn

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, this page is turning around of search functionality. So what I suggest you to implement here - to include search text into your routing parameters.

Your Search box which is help user to write down search query. Make it add search query to routing as some parameter, once user click `Search` button. It will be the only one responsibility of Search box, to change location URL, literally.

***Action***: User wrote down `Founder` in the search box input and pressed button Search.

***Result***: Location changed from `#/search/` to `#/search/Founder`

The search result view should just respond to the location change. If the search string is changed, it should do all needed calls to the server, and return, process and represent search result in the `Search result block`.

Comment: Though I know it's not a good practice, I don't want the term to appear in the URL. In addition, I simplified the search box; in reality it a more than just the input field (it's an entire form with 5-6 object for precised search).

Comment: It's good practice in case you want to represent a current state of the application, for instance - to share the link with someone. Could it be a situation in your app where search box presented , but search result is not? If not, why do you use 2 different ui-views for the single logical component?

Comment: That's a good question, You have a good valid point. I will create a plunker in a moment to share the result. How do you suggest to approach the whole search issue? It's not just the search term.
Do you think it should be like `#/search/:main-term?addi-field1=x&...?`

Comment: Yes, it looks like it is a nice solution for your case, to divide responsibilities of these two views. Your Search result box will be just looking at StateParams, and run related logic if `search` route is selected, and take string parameter to process it with server help. Let me know if you want me to update an answer.